# ruby on rails + iis7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis-7

I'm attempting to setup Ruby on Rails on IIS7.  I've been reading lots of guides, but this seems to be the only up-to-date version I can find:

http://blogs.msdn.com/dgorti/archive/2009/06/17/ruby-on-rails-with-iis-7-reloaded.aspx

Although I have set the correct network permissions (and even as a test given the everyone group full permissions for c:\ruby and c:{path to ruby app}) but still no joy.

I am stuck on IIS returning a http 500 error:

*"HTTP Error 500.0 - Internet Server Error
C:\ruby\bin\ruby.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly"*

Can any Ruby / IIS guru help?

Many thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link you provided, it looks like they used the FastCGI ISAPI route. I haven't myself used IIS for ages but, according to the book "Deploying Rails Applications", using FastCGI could be a bit tricky and recommends using ISAPI Rewrite instead.

Comment: Sadly, I've got to get it working via he fastcgi route... Thank you though!

Comment: FWIW, there seems to be various approaches to get IIS7, FastCGI and rails running; here's another step-by-step guide: http://hotgazpacho.org/2009/02/rails-230-iis7-fastcgi-rails-on-windows-ftw/

Hope you manage to get it to work.